# Why can't I access an inner static class in java with class object

Tags: java, class, static

When I access a static member with instance of class it works, then why error with static inner class?
In C++ we can access static members with instance as well the class name.
How is it different in Java.

```
class OuterClass{
    static public int x;
    public static void show(){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    public static class InnerClass{
        static public int y;
    }
}

public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        OuterClass obj = new OuterClass();
        obj.x= 5;
        System.out.println(obj.x);   // This runs fine 
        obj.InnerClass.y = 10;       // Error
        System.out.println(obj.InnerClass.y);
        OuterClass.InnerClass.y=10;  // This works why ?
        System.out.println(OuterClass.InnerClass.y);
    }
}
```

My apologies if this is a stupid question, new to Java hope you understand.
Regards

Comment: What is the *specific* error that gets reported?

Comment: [A static nested class interacts with the instance members of its outer class (and other classes) just like any other top-level class. In effect, a static nested class is behaviorally a top-level class that has been nested in another top-level class for packaging convenience.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)

Comment: Static is a property of the Class and not of its objects.

Comment: Error is InnerClass cannot be resolved or is not a feild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `obj.x = 5; System.out.println(obj.x);`

Yes, this works, but 'by accident'. The java language spec allows this, but note that *every* linting tool out there, and the current core engineering team of java, will **all** tell you that this is bad code style and you should not do this.

When in rome, be like the romans: If you prefer this code style, that's... immaterial. Don't write this. You're not in your own little bubble, you read the code that others write, and others will read and work with the code you write.

The only reason this is still allowed in java is because java doesn't like to break backwards compatibility.

The reason it's nuts is that `someExpr.someThing` rather strongly suggests that `someExpr` is in any way or form relevant. As in, that, at runtime, `someExpr` is evaluated and whatever object it points at (remember, in java, all variables except primitives are like C pointers, but in java we call them references. Potayto Potahto) is then used to either fetch that field or invoke that method.

But that is *not* what happens if `someThing` is a static concept: For a trivial proof of this, make `someExpr` null and note how that still just works (no NullPointerException is thrown), thus proving no dereferencing is taking place.

That's confusing. If `someThing` is static, then it belongs to the class and not any particular instance of it, so write it like that: `OuterClass.x`.

> `obj.InnerClass.y = 10; System.out.println(obj.InnerClass.y);`

Yes, error. Whilst you can refer to static methods and static fields by writing `x.fieldOrMethod` where x is an expression whose static (compile-time, not runtime) type is a type that has `fieldOrMethod` as field or method member, it works, but not if that is an inner type. Why? Because the java spec says so.

Note that inner types were added in java 1.1, and I'm pretty sure the lang team already realized that allowing `obj.staticThing` was a design mistake, so they intentionally decided not to expand on and prolong that mistake. It is further fuel on the fire as to why you should **not** make a habit out of this style; it doesn't consistently work.

> `OuterClass.InnerClass.y=10; System.out.println(OuterClass.InnerClass.y);`

Finally we get to proper code. Not just that it works, but this is how you **should** be doing it. `OuterClass.InnerClass` is *the* name of InnerClass: All classes are in effect 'static' when referring to just the class: It's not that there is one variant of InnerClass for each instance of OuterClass (not even if InnerClass is non-static): The **concept** "InnerClass" only exists once. There is only one instance of `java.lang.Class<?>` to represent "InnerClass", whether InnerClass is static or not. What other way would yourefer to `InnerClass`? `obj.InnerClass` makes zero sense - referring to InnerClass does not require an instance of obj - it is weird to supply irrelevant and unused information (in this case, the `obj` reference).

Comment: yes i was getting warning for this ```obj.x = 5; System.out.println(obj.x);``` thats what created confusion why this runs but not the other with static class